# React Native Warning: Prop `resizeMode = contain` should not be set directly on Image

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following warning in react native:

> Prop `resizeMode = contain` should not be set directly on Image.

Here is the code causing the warning:

```
<Image style={imageStyle} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('image!elephant')} />
```

This code works but it's not clear to me what the proper way to set the image to contain, cover or stretch.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to have been done in error and will be fixed in 0.7.0-rc:

> My understanding is that it should be used as a prop, and that using
>   it in the style was slated to be deprecated - @brentvatne

And:

> this is fixed in 0.7.0-rc actually: [4750856](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/47508566a0635bd54e7c67f66ac883c97a14ced2)
>   I'd wait until we merge in a fix for [#1750](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1750) before using that version though - @brentvatne

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1673

Comment: Cool, glad it wasn't me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's own [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#content) gives an example of setting `resizeMode` within the `Image` component as such:

```
<Image
  style={styles.resizeMode}
  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
  source={fullImage}
/>
```

Comment: I tried that too and still get the same warning.  Doesn't seem to make a difference.  :(

Answer (score -1):

I believe resizeMode should be set in imageStyle. Image supports resizeMode style key. Not sure though why there is also property.